# Rendering ejs template

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have following code in nodejs (I read temp.ejs file and get content as ejsHtml as string):

```
var html = EJS.render(ejsHtml, { A: '<div>smth</div>' } );
```

And in temp.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
      <%= A %>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
      &lt;div&gt; smth &lt;/div&gt;
</body>
</html>
```

Please tell me how to get Html and not that

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For outputting **escaped** html, you do the following:

```
<%= code %>
```

To output **unescaped** html, you would use the following

```
<%- code %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I used underscore to help me out. Only `<%=` or `<%-` did not work.

```
<%- _.unescape( data.textWithHtml ) %>
```

Comment: This also works with partials. In my particular case, I used [ejs-mate](https://github.com/JacksonTian/ejs-mate)