# textarea output doesn't interpet html tags

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, line-breaks, richtext

Since I searched forever and didn't find an answer that worked for me, I hope you can help me. I'm btw new to coding!

I'm building a recruiting website for my sister where she can upload job offers. For the description I used a `<textarea>` tag. I read that it can't interpret html tags and that's unfortunately true. I want my sister to be able to make at least line breaks because [the text looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hbbN.png).

I tried out many rich text editors like CKEditor but in the end it look good in the editor but the output stayed the same! I also tried `div` tags, but they won't submit to my database...

I'm using HTML, CSS, JavaScript, NodeJS and EJS. I don't know if it helps, but I'll put my ejs file here:

```
<% include ./partials/header %>

<div class="ui violet segment"><h1>Stelle bearbeiten: <%= job.title %></h1>

<div class="ui divider"></div>

<div style="padding:20px 0; width: 50%;">
<form class="ui form" action="/admin/jobs/<%= job.id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST">
<div class="field">
    <label>Titel</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" value="<%= job.title %>">
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label>Beschreibung</label>
    <textarea name="description"><%= job.description %></textarea>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label>Ort</label>
    <input type="text" name="location"  value="<%= job.location %>">
</div>


<div class="inline fields">
  <label for="jobtype">Art</label>

  <div class="field">
    <div class="ui radio checkbox">
      <input type="radio" name="jobtype" 
        <% if(job.jobtype === 'Freelancer'){ %>
          checked="checked"
        <% } %>
      value="Freelancer">
      <label>Freelance</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <div class="ui radio checkbox">
      <input type="radio" name="jobtype" 
        <% if(job.jobtype === 'Festanstellung'){ %>
          checked="checked"
        <% } %>
      value="Festanstellung">
      <label>Festanstellung</label>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="field">
  <label>Zeitraum</label>
  <input type="text" name="time"  value="<%= job.time %>">
</div>

<div class="inline fields">
  <label for="status">Status</label>

  <div class="field">
    <div class="ui radio checkbox">
      <input type="radio" name="status" 
        <% if(job.status === 'active'){ %>
          checked="checked"
        <% } %>
      value="active">
      <label>veröffentlicht</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <div class="ui radio checkbox">
      <input type="radio" name="status" 
        <% if(job.status === 'inactive'){ %>
          checked="checked"
        <% } %>
      value="inactive">
      <label>geheim</label>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<button class="ui teal button">Speichern</button>
</form>


</div>
</div>
<% include ./partials/footer %>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure what the issue is? You can get the `.value` of the `<texarea>` and append that HTML string to an HTML element outside of the `<textarea>`

Comment: After a week of despair I found the real problem and [the answer to my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356224/rendering-ejs-template)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an HTML textarea always displays text. So you can write yourself the javascript needed for rich content editor or use one of the thousand available.

Maybe you should give them another try and come back if you have questions about how to use them.